# How to save custom value in sales_flat_order_grid on order placement?

Tags: magento-1.9, php, event-observer, sales-order

I have to save the stock of each product when an order is placed.

The custom module is `Tbb_StockRegistrar`. It creates a column called `order_stock_message` in `sales_flat_order` and `sales_flat_order_grid` tables. This is OK.

Then, the observer should save the value in those tables (Not working):

**config.xml**

```
<events>
    <sales_order_place_after>
        <observers>                  
            <checkout_submit_all_after_handler>
                <type>model</type>                                   
                <class>Tbb_StockRegistrar_Model_Observer</class>
                <method>save</method>       
            </checkout_submit_all_after_handler>
        </observers>
    </sales_order_place_after>
</events>
```

**Observer.php**

```
<?php

class Tbb_StockRegistrar_Model_Observer
{

    public function save($observer)
    {
        $order  = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $stocks = $this->saveComment($order);
        $this->saveOrderGridColumn($order, $stocks);
    }

    protected function saveComment($order)
    {
        # Save the stocks as an order comment (Working)
    }

    protected function saveOrderGridColumn($order, $stocks)
    {
        $stockMessage = ... // It populates the message to be saved

        $orderModel = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order->getId());
        $orderModel->setOrderStockMessage($stockMessage);
        $orderModel->save();

    }

}
```

The method `setOrderStockMessage` is not saving anything. Why?

Plus, how can I store the same value in `sales_flat_order_grid` table on `sales_order_place_after` observer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to change as per below code config.xml

```
<events>
    <sales_order_place_after>
        <observers>                  
            <Tbb_StockRegistrar_Model_Observer>
                <type>model</type>                                   
                <class>Tbb_StockRegistrar_Model_Observer</class>
                <method>save</method>       
            </Tbb_StockRegistrar_Model_Observer>
        </observers>
    </sales_order_place_after>
</events>
```

Comment: Worked! TYVM!!!